# Separate properties file for multiple environments

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, spring-boot

I am trying to have separate property files for prod and dev environment.

I have two property files `application-prod.properties`, `application-dev.properties` placed in `classpath:/config`

I added VM option `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

According to what I understand from [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) and many other references on the web, on accessing Spring `Environment` as `environment.getProperty("")` the property in "application-dev.properties" should be loaded. However, I am getting null and as it seems the property files are not read by Spring.

I also tried defining both the files in `@PropertySource`. Doing this, the file defined second is picked up and the corresponding property is returned. Spring is not choosing the file based on the active profile.

Am I missing something?

I also came across a [issue raised](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12111) through some SO questions, but I am not sure if it refers to the same problem.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot with auto-configuration?

Comment: I am a noob. From what I understand, I am not using spring boot. I am using spring framework for autowiring (with context:annotation-config).
I am not sure if I am making sense here :|

Answer (score 3):

Right, so documentation you are pointing to is from Spring Boot project. That is not the same as Spring Framework. If you are not using Spring Boot, `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` wouldn't work.

You have two options:

1. Introduce Spring Boot to your project ans turn on auto-configuration (`@SpringBootApplication` or `@EnableAutoConfiguration`).
2. Use plain Spring Framework features like `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, but it doesn't give you same flexibility as Spring Boot features and you will need to create some boilerplate code to handle various envs.